# Java SaxParser trim the string after &amp;

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I want to parse this xml:

```
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/rf1/result2.xsd">
 <head>
  <variable name="uri"/>
  <variable name="id"/>
  <variable name="label"/>
</head>
<results distinct="false" ordered="true">
<result>
  <binding name="uri"><uri>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Davis_&amp;_Weight_Motorsports</uri></binding> 
  <binding name="label"><literal xml:lang="en">Davis &amp; Weight Motorsports</literal></binding>
  <binding name="id"><literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">5918444</literal></binding>
  <binding name="label"><literal xml:lang="en">Davis &amp; Weight Motorsports</literal></binding>
</result></results></sparql>
```

This is my handler:

```
public class DBpediaLookupClient extends DefaultHandler{

public DBpediaLookupClient(String query) throws Exception {
    this.query = query;
   HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("some_uri&query=" + query2);
    try {         
      client.executeMethod(method);       
      InputStream ins = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
      SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
      SAXParser sax = factory.newSAXParser();
      sax.parse(ins, this);


    } catch (HttpException he) {
      System.err.println("Http error connecting to lookup.dbpedia.org");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.err.println("Unable to connect to lookup.dbpedia.org");
    }
    method.releaseConnection();
  }

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {      
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("td") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("uri") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("literal")) {
      tempBinding = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    lastElementName = qName;
  }

  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {     
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("uri") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("literal") || qName.equalsIgnoreCase("td")) {
      if (!variableBindings.contains(tempBinding))
        variableBindings.add(tempBinding);
    }
  }

  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    String s = new String(ch, start, length).trim();
    if (s.length() > 0) {
      if ("td".equals(lastElementName)) {
        if (tempBinding.get("td") == null) {
          tempBinding.put("td", s);
        }           
      }

      else if ("uri".equals(lastElementName)) {
            if (tempBinding.get("uri") == null) {
                  tempBinding.put("uri", s);
                }
      }
      else if ("literal".equals(lastElementName)) {
            if (tempBinding.get("literal") == null) {
                  tempBinding.put("literal", s);
                }
      }
      //if ("URI".equals(lastElementName)) tempBinding.put("URI", s);
      if ("URI".equals(lastElementName) && s.indexOf("Category")==-1 && tempBinding.get("URI") == null) {
        tempBinding.put("URI", s);
      }
      if ("Label".equals(lastElementName)) tempBinding.put("Label", s);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
key: uri, value: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Davis_
key: literal, value: 5918444
key: literal, valueDavis
```

As you can see it gets seperated from the &

When I trace through the character() function I see that the lenght is wrong and is up to & instead of being up to the end of the string that I want to get as the result.

I copied this part of code and I don't know much about parser and handlers, I just know that much that I got from tracing the code, and wherever I searched it was said there should be `&amp;` instead of & in an xml document, which is the case here.

What should I do in this code to get the complete string not get trimed by & character?

Comment: Please post the xml you are parsing for some testing.

Comment: The only thing I can see that might be an issue is that some XML parsers might give you multiple `characters` events for the content of a single element.  I suggest using your debugger, with a breakpoint in the `characters` method to find out whether this is what's happening.  If it IS what's going on, then you'll have to make your `characters` method accumulate the text until the `endElement` method is called.

Comment: You're right. How should I know if that's the case that I need to accumulate? Is it a reasonable way if I set a switch on and off in startelement and endelement?

Comment: As I suggested.  Use your debugger, with a breakpoint in `characters` to see how many times it gets called, and with what characters.  That will tell you whether you need to accumulate.  If that's not the issue, then I'm not sure what to suggest; but this would be a good thing to try first.

Comment: It happens 3 times, with 1) the start of the string until the character before &, 2) "&" 3) the character after & until the end of the string. 1 and 3 is not known and each time might be different. So I think having a flag in startelement and endelement may work, not sure though. I will try that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't have a flag.  In your `startElement`, put an empty string into the `tempBinding` map, with the right key.  In your `characters`, get whatever's in the map, add on the characters that you've got, and put it back into the map.  Or, you could make it a bit more sophisticated and have `tempBinding` as a `Map<String,StringBuilder>` to save you from doing `String` concatenation.

Comment: In this example I only have one tag <result>...</result> in my <results/> tag, in the code I might have several <result/> tags. In that case your solution won't work.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?  You should only put the empty string into `tempBinding` if the tag  you're starting is `<literal>`.  If you do that, then the actual logic is exactly what you have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a lesson everyone has to learn when using SAX: the parser can break up text nodes and report the content in multiple calls to characters(), and it's the application's job to reassemble it (e.g. by using a StringBuilder). It's very common for parsers to break the text at any point where it would otherwise have to shunt characters around in memory, e.g. where entity references occur or where it hits an I/O buffer boundary.

It was designed this way to make SAX parsers super-efficient by minimizing text copying, but I suspect there's no real benefit, because the text copying just has to be done by the application instead.

Don't try and second-guess the parser as @DavidWallace suggests. The parser is allowed to break the text up any way it likes, and your application should cater for that.

Comment: This is what makes Stack Overflow great.  You ask a question about parsing with SAX, and you get an answer from Michael Kay.  Is there any other web site in the world where this kind of thing happens?